# mvn package command doesn't run successfully after mvn clean command if done from command prompt

Tags: maven-2, compiler-errors, m2eclipse, dependency-management, war

Hi
I get a weird error when I run mvn package command from the command line after executing mvn clean command.
The error is a compilation failure error.

This is a trace:

```
annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
06.04.2011 17.06.59 (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 @Override at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
06.04.2011 17.06.59 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
```

The strange thing is when I run mvn package command from eclipse IDE /m2eclipse it works perfectly fine (Even after running mvn clean from IDE as well as command prompt). when I run mvn package command from command prompt with the WAR file already built in the target folder by previous mvn package command the command works fine and a war file gets created and gets overwritten on the previously created war file in the target folder. But when I run mvn clean from IDE/Command prompt and then run mvn package from command prompt it gives me the above error and the compilation fails.
I want to automate this build process so I need to get this done from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse maven plugin also installs another copy of Maven (core). So, few of things would work differently while running maven command through eclipse VS Command line. To get away from this situation configure your eclipse to use maven installation you're expecting it to use. Window --> Preferences --> Maven--> Installations and change the setting to point to the local copy you've downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages gives the hint:

> use -source 5 or higher to enable
>   annotations
>   You have to configure the Compiler plugin to use at least Java 1.5 for compiling.

Comment: but then how it works fine when I do it from the IDE. One more thing is when I don't use mvn clean prior to mvn package (That is the target folder is there in the project folder with a WAR file and other folders created previously) it works fine even from the command line

Answer (score 2):

As other posters have started to point out, you're attempting to compile code that is language level 5 (Java 5) compliant (it uses annotations), but your compiler settings are set for language level 1.3.

See [Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) on the maven-compiler-plugin's page.

Comment: but then how it works fine when I do it from the IDE. One more thing is when I don't use mvn clean prior to mvn package (That is the target folder is there in the project folder with a WAR file and other folders created previously) it works fine even from the command line

Comment: It might help to see what settings you have, if any, for maven-compiler-plugin in your pom.xml. Also, what language level is Eclipse using for your project? If you're using m2eclipse, I'd assume it's taking the setting from the pom.xml, but it sounds like it might be using Java 1.5+ in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks buddy....worked for me.......I added - <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration> under mvn compiler plugin as shown in the above link in maven documentation