# m2e plugin problem. project does not build

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin

I am pretty new to Maven, I have installed the eclipse to maven plugin from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

even though through the command line the project compiles and builds the desired war, when i import the project to my eclipse i have lots of errors and it does not recognize all the dependencies.

I have tried to: run mvn eclipse:eclipse, purge the dependencies, importing it not through maven, setting the MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER to the .m2 folder.

but nothing works, Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow steps mentioned here?

[mvn package command doesn't run successfully after mvn clean command if done from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573173/mvn-package-command-doesnt-run-successfully-after-mvn-clean-command-if-done-from/5577310#5577310)